# ModBus on Dart/Flutter through Bluetooth?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, modbus

Our team develops custom device and an Android app which communicate through Bluetooth and [ModBus](https://libmodbus.org/), and we're going to recreate our app using Dart/Flutter so we will also have an iOS version. But is it possible to use ModBus with Bluetooth on this platform? I've found [modbus](https://pub.dev/packages/modbus) [package](https://pub.dev/documentation/modbus/latest/modbus/modbus-library.html) for Dart, but found nothing about using it with Bluetooth. Or, is there any analog to `modbus` which can be used on  our device programmed in C, Java Android app, and Dart?

Comment: Hello Aivan, can you be more specific? Do you want to use Modbus TCP or RTU? What Modbus devices will you be connecting to? What hardware will you be using to connect those devices to Bluetooth? Depending on the hardware you use you might have different software choices.

Comment: I think you can open a Bluetooth connection like you do with a serial port. You can try this new package I've published: https://pub.dev/packages/modbus_client